# Black screen appears for a short amount of time when changing from one Material App to another one

Tags: localization, flutter

Black screen appears for a short amount of time when changing from one Material App to another one. This only happens if I set  localizationDelegates of MaterialApp.

You can run the following repo to reproduce the issue:

https://github.com/figengungor/localization_black_screen

I am not sure what causes that black screen. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Why create a new materialapp when you can update its children?

Comment: I want to wrap MaterialApp with DataProvider when stream has data so all routes can access that data.

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't mean you have to recreate a MaterialApp

Comment: What is your suggestion?

Comment: Use InheritedWidgets such as `Theme` or some custom ones. You won't recreate the MaterialApp but the behavior is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue happens because you update the widget tree from

```
Foo
 MaterialApp
```

to

```
Foo
  Bar
    MaterialApp
```

This makes flutter hard reset the state of `MaterialApp`, triggering to loading.

You should avoid this in general. It'd be better to either always insert `Bar` with null datas, or use a `GlobalKey` as such:

```
final key = GlobalKey();
// ...

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final app = MaterialApp(key: key);
  return someCondition
    ? Bar(child: app)
    : app;
}
```

`GlobalKey` purposefully reuse the previous `Element` associated with the key

Comment: Thank you. GlobalKey solved the issue. But I had to do a couple more extra weird things , too. The thing is I am changing the home according to a condition. If it has data, it shows HomePage. But If it doesn't I show a InputScreen and from that screen you navigate to another screen(Splash) and this screen also stays on top of everything even if I have data and it supposed to show HomePage but I see in my Flutter Inspector both Splash and Home is in there under MaterialApp, so what I did was listening the stream and when there is data I pop SplashPage.

Comment: Do you mind creating another question or slack? I honestly don't get the problem and comments aren't ideal

Comment: Okey my brain started to work while updating the repo. Of course it'll show SplashScreen because I navigated to it from home.What was I thinking?Doh! So even though home is updated with my HomePage I need to go back from route stack to see it. So I ended up handling InputPage and SplashPage Content inside one page so no navigation business here. Thank you for your help and interest, Remi.